# Creating Tables in DokuWiki

Tags: wiki

I'm trying to create a table in DokuWiki, with a cell that vertically spans, however unlike the examples in the [syntax guide](http://www.dokuwiki.org/syntax#tables), the cell I want to create has more than one row of text.

The following is an ASCII version of what I'm trying to achieve

```
+-----------+-----------+
| Heading 1 | Heading 2 |
+-----------+-----------+
|           | Multiple  |
| Some text | rows of   |
|           | text      |
+-----------+-----------+
```

I've tried the following syntax

```
^ Heading 1 ^ Heading 2 ^
| Some text | Multiple  |
| :::       | rows of   |
| :::       | text      |
```

but this generates the output

```
+-----------+-----------+
| Heading 1 | Heading 2 |
+-----------+-----------+
|           | Multiple  |
|           +-----------+
| Some text | rows of   |
|           +-----------+
|           | text      |
+-----------+-----------+
```

I can't find anything in the DokuWiki documentation, so I'm hoping I'm missing something fundamentally simple?

Comment: p.s. adjusting the spelling of "DokuWiki" in the title may help others to find this question/answer in future searches.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
^ Heading 1 ^ Heading 2 ^
| Some text | Multiple\\ rows of\\ text |
```

All you need is line breaks within a table cell.  Enjoy!

Answer (score 3):

I know it's a long time after question was answered, but just to give more options to community:

You can also use plug-ins like EditTable for visual editing of tables (like in Microsoft Excel): https://www.dokuwiki.org/plugin:edittable

And the other options are listed here:
https://www.dokuwiki.org/tips:table_editing